How to query amplify database
How do i query out list of Questions where the course is equal to the one supplied in the argument, the following code returns nothing in some cases.
 final request = ModelQueries.list(
       Questions.classType,
        where: Questions.COURSE.eq(course),
        limit: 10
      );

